# Error in lightning InvalidDefinitionException

Tags: lightning-aura-components

> org.auraframework.throwable.quickfix.InvalidDefinitionException:
>   Invalid definition for null:Expense: null

```
<aura:component controller="ExpensesController">
    <aura:attribute name="expense" type="Expense"/>
    <h1>Hello Lightning</h1>
    <p>Amount:<ui:outputCurrency value="{!v.expense}"/></p>
    <p>Client:<ui:outputText value="{!v.expense.Amount__c}"/></p>
 <aura:handler name="init" action="{!c.doInit}" value="{!this}"/>
</aura:component>
```

Comment: Just append `__c` in attribute type.

Answer (score 1):

If the type is an custom object is it not expense__c

from [documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/ref_attr_types_object_salesforce.htm) . This is an attribute for an Expense__c custom object:

```
<aura:attribute name="expense" type="Expense__c" />
```